# While loop causes previous code to be skipped

Tags: java, swing, while-loop, do-while

I think I might just be doing something wrong so I decided to come here. I'm trying to write an "Aim Trainer" of sorts and there are no issues with it until one part.

In this part it checks if a button has been pressed. If it has, then it will remove the button from the JPanel and add some other stuff.

```
if(e.getSource() == startSixty) {
    milliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
    this.remove(startButton);
    this.remove(beginning);
    this.remove(startText);
    this.remove(startSixty);
    this.add(hitButton);
    validate();
    repaint();
    endCheck();
```

After this I have a while loop (simplified slightly for viewing pleasure) which is checking to see if 10 seconds has passed, once ten seconds passes, the code displays scores of how you did and stuff.

```
public void endCheck() {
        
        while (((System.currentTimeMillis() - milliseconds) / 1000) != 10) {
            System.out.println("1");
            if ((int) ((System.currentTimeMillis() - milliseconds) / 1000) == 10) {
                
                this.remove(hitButton);
                this.add(finishedHitCount);
                this.add(finishedMissCount);
                this.add(hitMissRatio);
                this.add(hitTimeRatio);
                validate();
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }
```

The while loop is working fine, the issue I'm having is that the code before it that removes stuff isn't working, almost like it's skipping that snippet of code.

Full Code (Might not be necessary but if you want it):

```
package TrainingButtons;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class GameFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener, MouseListener{
    
    JButton hitButton;
    JButton endButton;
    JButton startButton;
    JButton startSixty;
    Random random;
    JLabel finishedHitCount;
    JLabel finishedMissCount;
    JLabel hitMissRatio;
    JLabel totalTime;
    JLabel hitTimeRatio;
    JLabel beginning;
    JLabel startText;
    double hits;
    double misses;
    double milliseconds;
    double endTime;
    boolean found = true;
    Main main;

    GameFrame() {
        
        random = new Random();
        
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setResizable(true);
        addMouseListener(this);
        
        //startText Design
        startText = new JLabel("Quinn's Aim Trainer", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        startText.setSize(getWidth(), 100);
        startText.setFont(new Font("Apple Chancery", Font.BOLD, 75));
        startText.setLocation(0, 75);
        
        //beginning Design
        beginning = new JLabel("Press Start To Begin", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        beginning.setSize(getWidth(), 100);
        beginning.setFont(new Font("Copperplate", Font.BOLD, 75));
        beginning.setLocation(0, 225);
        
        //startSixty Design
        startSixty = new JButton();
        startSixty.setSize(350, 100);
        startSixty.setText("60 Second Round?");
        startSixty.setFont(new Font("Copperplate", Font.BOLD, 30));
        startSixty.setLocation((getWidth() - 650), (getHeight() / 2 - (startSixty.getHeight() / 2)));
        startSixty.addActionListener(this);
        startSixty.setOpaque(true);
        startSixty.setBorderPainted(false);
        startSixty.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        
        //hitButton Design
        startButton = new JButton();
        startButton.setSize(350,100);
        startButton.setText("Infinite Round?");
        startButton.setFont(new Font("Copperplate", Font.BOLD, 30));
        startButton.setLocation(300, (getHeight() / 2 - (startButton.getHeight() / 2)));
        startButton.addActionListener(this);
        startButton.setOpaque(true);
        startButton.setBorderPainted(false);
        startButton.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        
        //hitButton Design
        hitButton = new JButton();
        hitButton.setSize(25,25);
        hitButton.setLocation((getWidth() / 2 - (hitButton.getWidth() /2)), (getHeight() / 2 - (hitButton.getHeight() / 2)));
        hitButton.addActionListener(this);
        hitButton.setOpaque(true);
        hitButton.setBorderPainted(false);
        hitButton.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        
        //endButton Design
        endButton = new JButton();
        endButton.setSize(100, 50);
        endButton.setText("END");
        endButton.setLocation(((getWidth() /2) - 50), 0);
        endButton.addActionListener(this);
        endButton.setOpaque(true);
        endButton.setBorderPainted(false);
        endButton.setBackground(Color.RED);
        
        this.add(startText);
        this.add(startButton);
        this.add(startSixty);
        this.add(beginning);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == hitButton) {
            hitButton.setLocation(random.nextInt(this.getWidth()) - 13, random.nextInt(this.getHeight()) - 13);
            hits++;
        } else if(e.getSource() == startButton) {
            milliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
            this.remove(startButton);
            this.remove(beginning);
            this.remove(startText);
            this.remove(startSixty);
            this.add(hitButton);
            this.add(endButton);
            validate();
            repaint();
        } else if(e.getSource() == endButton) {
            //endTime = (milliseconds/1000);
            endTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() - milliseconds) / 1000;
            
            //finishedHitCount Design
            finishedHitCount = new JLabel("Total Hits: " + (int) hits, SwingConstants.CENTER);
            finishedHitCount.setSize(getWidth(), 100);
            finishedHitCount.setFont(new Font("Copperplate", Font.BOLD, 75));
            finishedHitCount.setLocation(0, 25);
            
            //finishedMissCount Design
            finishedMissCount = new JLabel("Total Misses: " + (int) misses, SwingConstants.CENTER);
            finishedMissCount.setSize(getWidth(), 100);
            finishedMissCount.setFont(new Font("Copperplate", Font.BOLD, 75));
            finishedMissCount.setLocation(0, 150);
            
            //hitMissRatio Design
            DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
            if (misses == 0) {
                hitMissRatio = new JLabel("Hit Miss Ratio: " + (int) hits, SwingConstants.CENTER);
            } else {
                String formatted = format.format(hits/misses);
                hitMissRatio = new JLabel("Hit Miss Ratio: " + formatted, SwingConstants.CENTER);
            }
            hitMissRatio.setSize(getWidth(), 100);
            hitMissRatio.setFont(new Font("Copperplate", Font.BOLD, 75));
            hitMissRatio.setLocation(0, 275);
            
            //totalTime Design
            totalTime = new JLabel("Total Time: " + endTime + " Seconds", SwingConstants.CENTER);
            totalTime.setSize(getWidth(), 100);
            totalTime.setFont(new Font("Copperplate", Font.BOLD, 75));
            totalTime.setLocation(0, 400);
            
            //hitTimeRatio Design
            String formatted2 = format.format(hits/endTime);
            hitTimeRatio = new JLabel("Hits Per Second: " + formatted2, SwingConstants.CENTER);
            hitTimeRatio.setSize(getWidth(), 100);
            hitTimeRatio.setFont(new Font("Copperplate", Font.BOLD, 75));
            hitTimeRatio.setLocation(0, 525);
            
            this.remove(hitButton);
            this.remove(endButton);
            this.add(finishedHitCount);
            this.add(finishedMissCount);
            this.add(hitMissRatio);
            this.add(totalTime);
            this.add(hitTimeRatio);
            validate();
            repaint();
        } else if(e.getSource() == startSixty) {
            System.out.println("3");
            milliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
            this.remove(startButton);
            this.remove(beginning);
            this.remove(startText);
            this.remove(startSixty);
            this.add(hitButton);
            validate();
            repaint();
            System.out.println("4");
            endCheck();
        }
    }
    
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        misses++;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
    
    public void endCheck() {
        
        //do {
        //for (int i = 0; i != 1;) {
        while (((System.currentTimeMillis() - milliseconds) / 1000) != 10) {
            System.out.println("1");
            if ((int) ((System.currentTimeMillis() - milliseconds) / 1000) == 10) {
                //finishedHitCount Design
                finishedHitCount = new JLabel("Total Hits: " + (int) hits, SwingConstants.CENTER);
                finishedHitCount.setSize(getWidth(), 100);
                finishedHitCount.setFont(new Font("Copperplate", Font.BOLD, 75));
                finishedHitCount.setLocation(0, 25);
                
                //finishedMissCount Design
                finishedMissCount = new JLabel("Total Misses: " + (int) misses, SwingConstants.CENTER);
                finishedMissCount.setSize(getWidth(), 100);
                finishedMissCount.setFont(new Font("Copperplate", Font.BOLD, 75));
                finishedMissCount.setLocation(0, 150);
                
                //hitMissRatio Design
                DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
                if (misses == 0) {
                    hitMissRatio = new JLabel("Hit Miss Ratio: " + (int) hits, SwingConstants.CENTER);
                } else {
                    String formatted = format.format(hits/misses);
                    hitMissRatio = new JLabel("Hit Miss Ratio: " + formatted, SwingConstants.CENTER);
                }
                hitMissRatio.setSize(getWidth(), 100);
                hitMissRatio.setFont(new Font("Copperplate", Font.BOLD, 75));
                hitMissRatio.setLocation(0, 275);
                
                //hitTimeRatio Design
                String formatted2 = format.format(hits/endTime);
                hitTimeRatio = new JLabel("Hits Per Second: " + formatted2, SwingConstants.CENTER);
                hitTimeRatio.setSize(getWidth(), 100);
                hitTimeRatio.setFont(new Font("Copperplate", Font.BOLD, 75));
                hitTimeRatio.setLocation(0, 525);
                
                this.remove(hitButton);
                this.add(finishedHitCount);
                this.add(finishedMissCount);
                this.add(hitMissRatio);
                this.add(hitTimeRatio);
                validate();
                repaint();
                //i = 1;
            }
            System.out.println("2");
        }
        //}
        //}while (!found);
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for an explanation of what's going wrong and [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for a possible solution

Comment: This seems to have worked thank you so much. I originally tried to use a timer on it but I wasn't sure for the parameters.